# syntastic vim: How to return to a regular "insert" mode?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I added Syntastic plugin to Vim: https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic.

When I write code and type: ":w", I do get an error check that looks like this: 
[image]

What do I have to do to return to the state where I was before watching the error mode? I just want to return to "regular" insert mode in vim.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: 
press ESC key and then type:

> :lclose

Comment: That would just close the error window.  It wouldn't "return [you] to the state where [you were] before watching the error mode".  You need `:SyntasticReset`.